# NetworkOnMainThreadException using OkHttp with RxJava2

Tags: android, okhttp, rx-java2

I am trying to learn Rxjava2. I am facing a problem i.e, NetworkOnMainThreadException during network call using okHttp. I have to use only okHttp libary.

This is my method where I have written the code of RxJava2 for calling Login API.

```
@Override
public void onServerLoginClick(LoginRequest.ServerLoginRequest serverLoginRequest) {
    HttpParamObject httpParamObject = ApiGenerator.onServerLogin(serverLoginRequest);
    Service service = ServiceFactory.getInstance(activity, AppConstants.TASKCODES.LOGIN);

    try {
        Observable.just(service.getData(httpParamObject))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((Consumer<? super Object>) getObserver());
    } catch (JSONException | IOException | RestException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Subscriber<LoginResponse> getObserver(){
    return new Subscriber<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
            getUiView().showToast(loginResponse.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    };

}
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything? Please help me.

Comment: @ADM  problem with integrating OkHttp Library with Rxjava2. No problem in the code of OkHttp.

Comment: Ok. Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488683/android-rxjava-with-okhttp-networkonmainthreadexception) if you haven't already .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OkHttp Library - NetworkOnMainThreadException on simple post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135338/okhttp-library-networkonmainthreadexception-on-simple-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `service.getData(httpParamObject)` in the main thread and passing that result to `Observable.just`. So your `subscribeOn` has no effect.

Check the documentation of [Observable.create](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html) and use it instead of `Observable.just`

Comment: Can you give a full example please. I read Observable.create and I don't see how to do it (emit only one item).

Comment: You can find full examples in several languages in the documentation I posted in the answer...

Comment: Using rxjava2, what I was looking for was 'fromCallable(...)'.

Answer (score -2):

just remove Observable.just() as follows

```
  service.getData(httpParamObject)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((Consumer<? super Object>) getObserver());
```